# Split phone calls by day

Tags: calls, call-history

Is there any Android app that allows me to see my phone calls (number, total time) split by each day?

Or do I have to dig it out manually from my call log (quite unhandy)?

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for a "sort by day" feature or App correct?

Comment: Correct, but not exactly. "Sort by day" will only sort... by day. I have to summarize number of calls and total length myself. I'm more like looking for "split by day", which will sort by day and summarize, how many calls (lasting totally how long) I made each and every day.

Answer (score 0):

try call stats
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.movinapp.calls
there are other similar apps on Google play.